# How to use Developer Console to execute a controller extension

Tags: apex

How to execute the Apex class in Developer Console

```
public class myControllerExtension {



    private final Account acct;

         public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
                 system.debug(stdController);

            this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
                 system.debug(this.acct);

        }

          public String getGreeting() {

            return 'Hello ' + acct.name + ' (' + acct.id + ')';

        }

    }
```

Comment: Tushar answer is correct.. if you want to use in test class then you need to create account record in test class and then use account record for standard controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Account acc = [select Id,name from account limit 1]; //if in your org account record does not exist then create one
  ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(acc);
    myControllerExtension  ext = new myControllerExtension (stdController );
    ext.getGreeting();
```

Use these lines of code to execute the class same as test class.

Comment: Can you explain why you are executing like this? , I dont Know, what actually normal class describes? why you are using like this

Comment: @Salesforce this is a standard approach. What did you don't understand here.

Comment: In the Thirdline we can Directly give the Input as myControllerExtension  ext = new myControllerExtension (acc ); why?

Comment: no you can't give because you are using stardcontroller as a reference so you need to initialize that first.